# Why prompted for username when pushing despite having set up ssh?

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key

I am puzzled, when pushing, I am always prompted for my username and password but I have set up a public key.

I can successfully log in using `ssh -T git@github.com`.

To make things even more strange, on my laptop (which I set up first), I am able to clone a repo via ssh by clicking on "use ssh" or https. On my tower (that has the problem) there is only https.

It says "Use git or checkout with SVN using the web URL"

I have a ssh server running on the tower but not listening on port 22 because I forwarded a port from my router and prefered to use a nonstandard one, could this be the problem? How could I make the ssh server listen on two ports if that was indeed the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting SSH up on GitHub doesn't magically make all of your connections use SSH. You might want to connect to some remotes over SSH and some over HTTPS. Your remote is probably configured to use HTTPS.

You can use [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote--v) to see what URLs your remotes use, e.g.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/github/hub.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/github/hub.git (push)
```

And [`git remote set-url <remote> <new-url>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem) to update them to the SSH URL, e.g.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:github/hub.git
origin  git@github.com:github/hub.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:github/hub.git (push)
```